# Django slug and id as URL redirect

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get something in Django, already for hours but without success. However I'm trying to use friendly urls like 'my-post-title-1234', where the number at the end is the post's id and the rest before that is the post's title. I got the url by using the slug and the id and I can retrive both in the view. So I check if ID exists and if it exists I do the rest, and if it doesn't exist I do 404 DoesNotExist. Inside the model I generated slug field and slugified title.

Everything works so far except one thing: User is able to write bla-bla-bla-1234 and it will still show him same data (since id exist). What I would like is following:

If user type in 'bla-bla-bla-1234' I would like to redirect him to correct slug 'my-post-title-1234'.

This is how my url looks like:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)-(?P<post_id>\d+)/$', views.post, name='post')
```

This is my model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length = 125)
    text = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(null = False, blank = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.post_title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is from my view:

```
def post(request, slug, post_id):
    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(id = post_id)
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Post does not exist")
    return HttpResponse(post_id)
```

So the question is: how do I redirect(change url) to the correct slug from 'bla-bla-bla-1234' to 'my-post-title-1234', if user type in slug incorrectly while id is still good.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would recommend putting the `post_id` behind another slash `url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/(?P<post_id>\d+)/$', views.post, name='post')`. I think the reason this is not working for you, perhaps another URL is picking up your link, You can also try to move the URL above other links so it is processed first.

Comment: So by that my URL would looks like /my-post-title/1234/, is that correct? And still have no idea how to redirect or something...

Comment: The majority of websites put the ID before the slug, like `/1234-my-title-slug`

Comment: Correct, if the slug object exist, you should be able to use the `123-my-title` URL. Just make sure another URL with he same structure is not already in place

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems like you just need to check if the slug is correct, and if not do a redirect.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect

def post(request, slug, post_id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    if obj.slug != slug:
        return redirect('post', slug=obj.slug, post_id=obj.pk)
```

Note that there's a built-in shortcut for your first four lines: `get_object_or_404`. Also, be aware that calling an object within the function the same name as the function itself can lead to confusion; avoid doing that (which is why I've use `obj` above.)

Comment: Dude thanks a lot, worked like a charm and perfectly. All I had to change from your answer and according to django documentation (shortcut helpers): 
obj = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)

Answer (score 0):

In Django redirect comes with parameters, you can simply pass the slug in redirect by putting a ",".

```
return redirect("post",slug=slug)
```